# Input type="submit" en modal de Bootstrap no funciona

Tags: php, html, mysql, bootstrap

Estoy haciendo un CRUD para las tablas de mi base de datos y estoy utilizando tres modals: crear, editar y eliminar. El modal de crear y eliminar funcionan correctamente pero el input type="submit" del modal edit no hace nada. Este es el código:

```
<div class="modal fade" id="edit_<?php echo $row['Id_producto']; ?>" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
    <div class="modal-dialog">
        <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-header">
                <h4 class="modal-title" id="myModalLabel">Editar Producto</h4>
                <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">&times;</button>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-body">
                <form method="POST" action="controlador/update.php?id=<?php echo $row['Id_producto']; ?>" enctype="multipart/form-data">
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label>Nombre</label>
                        <input type="text" class="form-control" name="producto" value="<?php echo $row['nombre_producto']; ?>">
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label>Costo</label>
                        <input type="text" class="form-control" name="costo" value="<?php echo $row['precio_costo_producto']; ?>">
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label>Precio de Venta</label>
                        <input type="text" class="form-control" name="precio" value="<?php echo $row['precio_venta_producto']; ?>">
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label>Stock Mínimo</label>
                        <input type="text" class="form-control" name="stock_minimo" value="<?php echo $row['stock_min_producto']; ?>">
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label>Imágen</label>
                        <input type="file" class="form-control" name="imagen">
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label>Proveedor</label>
                        <select class="form-select mb-3" name="proveedor_p">
                            <option selected disabled>--Seleccionar proveedor--</option>
                            <?php
                            $sql="SELECT * FROM proveedores";
                            foreach ($con->query($sql) as $row) {
                                echo "<option name='proveedor_p' value'".$row['Id_proveedor'] . "'>" . $row['razon_social_proveedor'] . "</option>";
                            }
                            ?>
                        </select>
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label>Categoría</label>
                        <select class="form-select mb-3" name="categoria">
                            <option selected disabled>--Seleccionar proveedor--</option>
                            <?php
                            $sql="SELECT * FROM categorias";
                            foreach ($con->query($sql) as $row) {
                                echo "<option name='categoria' value'".$row['Id_categoria'] . "'>" . $row['nombre_categoria'] . "</option>";
                            }
                            ?>
                        </select>
                    </div>
                    <div class="modal-footer">
                        <input type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal" value="Cancelar">
                        <input type="submit" name="edit" class="btn btn-info" value="Guardar">
                    </div>
                </form>
            </div> 
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Es prácticamente la misma estructura del modal de agregar pero por alguna razón este no funciona y no he podido averiguar la razón.

Comment: He visto que lo tienes como un boton en vez de como un input de tipo submit

Comment: Ese botón es para cerrar el modal y si funciona, debajo del button está el tipo submit